# childwindow focus function does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, childwindow

I am trying to open a url of my application in a new tab and when user clicks on same link, it will focus on the open tab. This works fine in chrome. IE its does not work. Does IE require any other piece of code?

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var childWindowTab;

        function openTab() {
            var pathName = '/myurl';
            var tabExists = false;
            if (childWindowTab) {
                if (childWindowTab.location.pathname === pathName) {
                    if (!childWindowTab.closed) {
                        console.log(childWindowTab, childWindowTab.focus());
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            childWindowTab.focus();
                        });
                        tabExists = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!tabExists) {
                childWindowTab = window.open(pathName + window.location.search, '_blank');
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <a href="#" onclick="openTab()">opne tab</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have in IE it works for me. IE version 11.165.17134.0, update version 11.0.75

Comment: My version is 11.0.9? How about yours?

Comment: When you click on link second time whats the behavior you are seeing?